# Preparing for shifting

Tags: foundation

One concern for any new construction is shifting, which happens most immediately after a building is erected, but all buildings will shift and lean gradually over the years. Even if a building's foundations are set on bedrock, the natural movement of the earth will cause that rock to shift and cant over time.

Is there any method for preparing a foundation so that it will be easier to adjust in later years. One approach I can think of is to put the foundation on piles. The advantage of this is that to later re-balance the building only the piles need to be adjusted, rather than a whole basement floor. Is there any wisdom on this subject?

Comment: Short of 100 year old stone foundations on minimal footings, who "adjusts" their foundation? The movement you describe, when discussing buildings built to modern standards, is trivial.

Comment: In particular, who adjusts their foundation "DIY" style?